# How to generate composer.json from the Laravel vendor directory

Tags: laravel

Unfortunately, I deleted composer.json and composer.lock, but my vendor folder is intact and has all dependency packages installed. Is there a way to generate composer.json through the vendor folder? Any way to reverse engineer?

Comment: I don't think so. But you use GIT/SVN or have backups, don't you?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41184297/633440.